# C++: best practice to get a loop when user input is wrong

Tags: c++, loops, goto

We have 1 question and 3 different error messages. Which is the best way to have this question in loop until we get the right answer? I know `goto` is not the best practice, but it is really easy to use.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()

{
    int first_event = 1930;
    int curent_year = 2021;
    int input_year;
    int event_occurence = 4;

    firstquestion:
        std::cout << "When did you watch your first World Cup ?"   <<std::endl;
        std::cin >> std::setw(4) >> input_year;
        
        if (input_year < first_event)
        {
            std::cout << "Sorry, there was no World Cup prior to 1930. Please enter a valid date! " << std::endl;
            goto firstquestion;
        }
            

        if (input_year > curent_year)
        {
            std::cout << "Sorry, we are not there yet. Please enter a valid date...";
            std::cout << std::endl;
            goto firstquestion;
        }

        if (input_year % 2 != 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Sorry, no World Cup was held in " <<input_year <<". Please enter a valid date! ";
            goto firstquestion;
        } }
```

Comment: *I know `goto` is not the best practice, but it is really easy to use.* It is really easy to write. It is harder to prove correct, still harder to debug if it's not correct, and an absolute <expletive deleted> to maintain even when it is correct because someone who's not as smart/careful as you were will <expletive deleted> it up. I also find defending `goto` in code reviews soaks up more time than not using it in the first place because no one will believe you used it correctly and covered all your bases unless you can conclusively prove it, something you'll have to do over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()

{
    int first_event = 1930;
    int curent_year = 2021;
    int input_year;
    int event_occurence = 4;

    while(true) {
       std::cout << "When did you watch your first World Cup ?"   <<std::endl;
        std::cin >> std::setw(4) >> input_year;
        
        if (input_year < first_event)
        {
            std::cout << "Sorry, there was no World Cup prior to 1930. Please enter a valid date! " << std::endl;
           continue;
        }
            

        if (input_year > curent_year)
        {
            std::cout << "Sorry, we are not there yet. Please enter a valid date...";
            std::cout << std::endl;
           continue;
        }

        if (input_year % 2 != 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Sorry, no World Cup was held in " <<input_year <<". Please enter a valid date! ";
           continue;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Rationalle:

We use a loop to loop over the question and error messages. But then we need a way to break out of the loop if everything is ok. So loop runs infinitely and when an error is found, then `continue` restarts the loop. if no error is found, then the final `break` statement, exits the infinite loop.

Comment: @StackDanny, true multiple messages can appear, although this might be a requirement, anyway reverted to original version, simnply wanted to avoid explixit break statement

Comment: I know there is a 'cin.fail()' solution, which might be better if the input does not match the variable type but must be used with `cin.ignore` and `cin.clear` and it looks even more complicated.  Maybe there is a simpler way.